# Does it matter where I create the Ticker?

Tags: go

Is there any difference between

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)

go func() {
    for _ = range ticker.C {
        fmt.Print("Tick")
    }
}()

time.Sleep(3)
ticker.Stop()
```

and

```
var ticker *time.Ticker

go func() {
    ticker = time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
    for _ = range ticker.C {
        fmt.Print("Tick")
    }
}()

time.Sleep(3)
ticker.Stop()
```

in terms of thread-safeness, especially when the work in the function takes longer than a tick's period?

I am asking because (when stopping the Ticker is not required) the latter can be shortened to

```
go func() {
    for ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second) ;; <-ticker.C {
        fmt.Print("Tick")
    }
}()
```

while the former cannot. This form has the additional advantage that the first tick is triggered right away.

Comment: There is no difference actually. But it is good practice to pass the required variables from enclosing scope as parameters to goroutines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version of the code is wrong: it has a race condition.

```
var ticker *time.Ticker

go func() {
    ticker = time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
    for _ = range ticker.C {
        fmt.Print("Tick")
    }
}()

time.Sleep(3)
ticker.Stop()
```

There's no synchronization between the assignment to `ticker` inside the goroutine and the use of `ticker` in the `ticker.Stop()` call.

In practice this will almost always be harmless because of the long `time.Sleep(3)`, but such races should be avoided if possible because even if they're harmless today they may cause trouble later. For example, if instead of `Sleep` you have some code that takes a variable amount of time, you may see nil pointer panics if that code happens to take a very short amount of time.

So for that reason, I'd always use the first version of your code (the one that creates the `ticker` outside the goroutine).

The third version of the code (where the `ticker` is used entirely inside the goroutine) is also good. I'd definitely use this shorter version of the code where the ticker is defined inside the goroutine if that's possible. The shortness of the code is nice, but I also like that the code outside doesn't see the ticker at all, so it's easy for the reader of the code to understand the scope of the ticker.

Comment: You say "the third version is also good". So that means the Ticker will work properly, even if it's defined in the same Goroutine that is doing the work?

Comment: @AndreKR yes, using variables in the same goroutine that they're defined is normal. It may help to understand that all programs have at least one goroutine -- the one that runs your code in main!

Comment: I thought maybe when the goroutine was busy the Ticker somehow doesn't get a chance to send the next tick to the channel, but on second thought that doesn't really make sense, the ticker will need another internal goroutine in any case.